# Fisher's exact test (one-sided, greater) gives p-value = 1

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, p-value, fishers-exact-test

I have a contingency table that looks like this

```
                      | dataset$sexual_feedback 
dataset$artist_gender |         0 |         1 | Row Total | 
----------------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
               Female |       967 |        33 |      1000 | 
                      |     0.967 |     0.033 |     0.500 | 
----------------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
                 Male |       993 |         7 |      1000 | 
                      |     0.993 |     0.007 |     0.500 | 
----------------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
         Column Total |      1960 |        40 |      2000 | 
----------------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
```

Now if I run fishers exact test in R (since i have a directed hypothesis I am using the one-sided (greater) test) my p-value equals 1. 
Why is that and what do I need to do to get the correct p-value?

Here is the result from the `fisher.test()`

```
fisher.test(dataset$artist_gender, dataset$sexual_total, alternative = "greater") #                  Fisher's exact test: one-sided (greater)

    Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data

data:  dataset$artist_gender and dataset$sexual_feedback
p-value = 1
alternative hypothesis: true odds ratio is greater than 1
95 percent confidence interval:
0.09028557        Inf
sample estimates:
odds ratio 
0.2067188
```

Thank you.

Comment: In fact the p-value is not exactly 1 it just prints that way. If you extract it from the object returned by fisher.test you will see that. I suspect this is not the important issue though.

Answer (score 1):

With 0.21, your sample odds ratio is far below 1, so there is absolutely no evidence that the true odds ratio is above 1 (H1). A p value of 1 makes perfect sense.

Maybe you mixed up the specification of the alternative hypothesis, but statistics can't help you out with this. Of key importance are the following questions, which you should be able to answer with a clear 'yes':

- do I know what a (sample) odds ratio is?
- am I comfortable about hypothesis tests, especially about Fisher's exact test?
- do my data satisfy the assumptions to run such test?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming, that you would like to find out, whether there is a positive association between your two variables. So, your setting is the following:

$H_{0}:\theta=1 \\
H_{a}:\theta>1$

Where $\theta$ is the odds ratio. If the odds ratio *equals to* $1$, then there is no association between the variables. On the contrary, if the odds ratio is *greater than* $1$, then there is a positive association between the two variables.

> [...]my p-value equals 1. Why is that and what do i need to do to get the correct p-value?

The p-value=1 means that you failed to reject the $H_{0}$, i.e. there is no positive association between your variables. I don't think that you need to correct it. 
Fisher's exact test is recommended for small sample sizes, and your sample size is relatively large. If you calculate the test by hand, you will see that it results in huge factorials.

$\large{p=\frac{{a+b \choose a}{c+d \choose c}}{{n \choose a+c}}=\frac{{a+b \choose b}{c+d \choose d}}{{n \choose b+d}}=\frac{(a+b)!(c+d)!(a+c)!(b+d)!}{a!b!c!d!n!}}$

With R:

```
f=function(x){
  return(factorial(x))
}

(f(967+33)*f(993+7)*f(967+993)*f(33+7))/(f(967)*f(33)*f(993)*f(7)*f(2000))

# result:
[1] NaN
```